# Visual Studio 2015 "nuget" issue?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, discord, discord.net

I've been trying to install a NuGet package on Visual Studio, but I've been getting an error. When I install Discord.Net on the package manager, it said it worked, but I don't get the package. However, when I use the console I get an error. Here's what I get (this is about in the middle of the output highlighted in yellow):

```
Successfully installed 'RestSharp 105.2.3' to Userbot
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'WebSocket4Net.0.14.1' does not exist in project 'Userbot'
Removed package 'RestSharp.105.2.3' from 'packages.config'
Removed package 'Nito.AsyncEx.3.0.1' from 'packages.config'
Removed package 'Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.3' from 'packages.config'
Package 'WebSocket4Net.0.14.1' does not exist in folder            
'C:\Users\Josh\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Userbot\packages'
```

Then here's a message at the end highlighted in red:

```
Install-Package : Could not find file 
'C:\Users\Josh\.nuget\packages\websocket4net\0.14.1\websocket4net.0.14.1.nupkg'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Discord.Net
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

And that's the end of the package. And here's the weird part, other packages install fine.

Does anyone know the issue?
Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Are you able to install if you install WebSocket4Net manually first?

Comment: I don't know what WebSocket4Net is

Comment: Nevermind, thank you. I didn't even think of that, lol. I've been trying to fix this for a long time.

Comment: If you go to Nuget for [discord.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Discord.Net/) you can see [WebSocket4Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebSocket4Net/) is a dependency and that it is "a .NET websocket client implementation".

Comment: Could you please check the default Package Sources “nuget.org” is enable (Tools->NuGet Package Manager-> Package Manager Settings->Package Sources)? And make sure the value “All” is select for Package Sources when you use the console. You can download the dependency 'WebSocket4Net.0.14.1' from the NuGet.org (https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebSocket4Net/0.14.1) and set it to the Userbot\packages.